# What is the # for in the Mongoose API docs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I've been searching and can't find an answer. I'm new to Mongoose, and programming in general, and I've been reading the API docs to better understand what Mongoose can do. In the docs they have two ways of accessing an object property, through "dot" notation and through "#" notation? I'm not sure what the "#" represents. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely a documentation thing: the `#` is generally used to signify an *instance method* and the `.` a *class method* (also called a *static* method).

For instance:

- [`Schema#set`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-set): this means that *instances* of the class `Schema` will have a method called `set()`. Example:

  ```
  var dogSchema = new Schema(...); // create an instance of `Schema`
  dogSchema.set('strict');         // call the instance method `set()`
  ```

  Notice that you don't actually use the `#` character here, it's still a `.` in real code.
- [`Schema.indexTypes`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema.indexTypes): this means that the class `Schema` *itself* has a method `indexTypes()`. Example:

  ```
  var types = Schema.indexTypes(); // get the list of index types
  ```

More on instance and class/static methods in JavaScript can be found [here](https://abdulapopoola.com/2013/03/30/static-and-instance-methods-in-javascript/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the link. I really appreciate it.